# Output the highest average using functions

Tags: c++, arrays, file, max

I am supposed to create a function which receives the arrays as parameters and which searches for the student with the highest average of the 3 grades and return to main the location of the student in the array.

The 4 arrays are:
Student number(9 digits)
Math grade
Science grade
English grade

And finally, it's supposed to read the data from the file into the array.

File data is:

```
123456789
60
70
80
987654321
70
80
90
999888777
75
85
65
111222333
55
65
75
444555666
63
73
83
```

I need help with how to read the file data using the arrays and functions.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int findHighest(int Mgrade[5], int Sgrade1[5], int Egrade[5], long Snumber[5]);

main()
{
    int Mgrade[5], Sgrade[5], Egrade[5];
    long Snumber[5];

    char num_from_file;
    ifstream infile;
    char mystring[20];
    int grade;
    infile.open("testdata.txt", ios::in);

    if (infile)
    {

        cout<<"File opened successfully\n";
        {
            do
            {

                infile.get(mystring,21); //(example from other program)
                infile.ignore(80,'\n');// (what should go here instead)

                infile>> grade;//(example from other program)
                infile.ignore(80,'\n');// (what should go here instead)

                if (infile.eof())
                {
                    break;
                }

                cout<<mystring<<'\t'<<grade<<endl<<endl;
                //cout<<'\t'<<num_from_file<<endl;
            }
            while(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"error opening file";
    }

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should we guess how the file looks like?

Comment: `if (infile.eof()) break;` is basically a `while (! eof)`, [and those suck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). You're setting yourself up for some undetected IO errors.

Comment: `infile>> grade;` tries to read into an array of `int`s. I think you are missing an array index.

Comment: `infile.get(mystring,21) ;` tries to read 21 characters into a 20 character  buffer. This can go very wrong.

Comment: @Lanting i added it now

Comment: @user4581301 that's from other code, ignore it. I just need help with how to read the data file using the arrays and functions

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    int Mgrade[5], Sgrade[5], Egrade[5];
    long Snumber[5];
    std::ifstream input("testdata.txt");
    int index = 0, counter = 0;
    for( std::string line; getline( input, line ); ) {
        if(counter == 4) {
            counter = 0;
            index++;
        }
        if(counter == 0) {
            Snumber[index] = std::stol(line);
        } else if(counter == 1) {
            Mgrade[index] = std::stoi(line);
        } else if(counter == 2) {
            Sgrade[index] = std::stoi(line);
        } else if(counter == 3) {
            Egrade[index] = std::stoi(line);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code reads the file (variable `input` in the code) line by line and uses a for loop to achieve that.

In every iteration of the loop, the variable `line` will contain the current line of the file that are we are reading. For example, in the first iteration, `line` will be equal to `"123456789"`.

Now I use two integers, `index` and `counter`. The first is used to index the arrays, since we are reading the first student, we want to populate the first cell of every array (that would be an `index` equal to 0).

`counter` is used in order to keep track of how many lines are been read for the `idnex`-th student. We expect to read 4 lines for every student, so `counter` will be 0 when we read his number, 1 when we read his math grade, 2 when we read his science grade and 3 when we read his English grade. The counter gets increased by one, in the end of every iteration.

Now, when `counter` is equal to 4, that means that we should start reading data for the next student, thus we have to increment `index` by one, so that for example if we were reading data for the first student(`index` equal to 0), now we would need (`index` equal to 1).

Moreover, `counter` should be re-initialized to 0, so that we read his number and grades correctly, with the if-else statements.

Comment: [`std::stoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) is defined in `string` header and is C++11 feature. It just converts a string to an integer, so you could implement it yourself or google it. However, I highly recommend to use a compiler that supports C++11 (since it's not that new). For example, with an old GCC, you can use `-std=c++0x` flag to enable the C++11 features, like this: `g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11`. @user8859795

Comment: Yes you could it with [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) too, although you should keep up with the new functions. Example: `#include <cstdlib>` and `atoi(line.c_str());`. Similary, with [`atol()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atol/), you would do `atol(line.c_str());`.

Comment: It's ok @user8859795. Well `std` is just a namespace, and these functions are defined in it, don't get confused about it now. I updated my answer with explanation, hope that helps. I insist on my solution over your, since it will help you learn a bit. =)

Comment: @user8859795 no this isn't the way Stack Overflow works. We post here, so that future users can see the solutions as well.

Comment: Well, given OP's input file, maybe a simple `int i = 0; while (i < 5 && input >> Snumber[i] >> Mgrade[i] ...) {... ++i; ...}` could be enough.